# SQL Server Spatial Types

Tags: sql, types, dataset, geospatial, sqlgeography

I'm trying to create a `SpatialObject` in C# and pass it to my SQL Server database via a 
`DataSet`, but I can't figure how to pass it to the `DataSet` :/

When I try to add the element to the params of DS it just get as param

```
CONVERT(geography, '')
```

but do not receive anything, is there any way I can pass the object to the DS or should I do it via a stored procedure?

Here is the part of my code I'm using

```
SqlGeographyItem.BeginGeography(OpenGisGeographyType.Point);

string RadioLatLng = Points.Remove(Points.Length - 1);
string[] tokens = RadioLatLng.Split(',');

decimal.TryParse(HiddenRadio.Value, out Radio);

SqlGeographyItem.BeginFigure(Convert.ToDouble(tokens[1]), Convert.ToDouble(tokens[0]));
SqlGeographyItem.EndFigure();            
SqlGeographyItem.EndGeography();

SqlGeographyFig = SqlGeographyItem.ConstructedGeography;
SqlGeographyFig.STBuffer(Convert.ToDouble(Radio));

DS_GeofenceTableAdapters.Geofence1TableAdapter ta_geocercas = new DS_GeofenceTableAdapters.Geofence1TableAdapter();
DS_GeofenceTableAdapters.GeofenceClientTableAdapter tagc = new GeofenceClientTableAdapter();

int IdGeo = Convert.ToInt32(ta_geocercas.InsertQuery(4, this.txt_nombre.Text, Type, Points, Buffer, DateTime.Now, "Active", Radio, Color, route));
```

Comment: I think this SO question shows a good example of creating a geometry object in code and then sending it to the db using a SqlParameter of the correct type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704173/parametrizing-geometry-sql-command-c-sharp-in-asp-net-not-working.